# Vertical headers in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there a way to rotate 90º the column headers of a JTable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out Darryl's [Vertical Table Header Cell Renderer](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/06/vertical-table-header-cell-renderer/).

Comment: One problem with this is that this doesn't respect os themes :(

Answer (score 3):

This is little tricky. At first, you need to cast JTable headers to JLabels. It's just like

```
 ((JLabel)table.getTableHeader()
```

Then **rotate** JLabels. It's already answered [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620929/rotate-a-swing-jlabel)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps, I haven't tested it though:

```
class RotatedTableCellRenderer extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {  
    protected int m_degreesRotation = -90;  

    public RotatedTableCellRenderer(int degrees) {  
        m_degreesRotation = degrees;  
    }  

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,   
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {  

        try {  
            this.setText(value.toString());  
        } catch(NullPointerException ne) {  
                this.setText("Nullvalue");  
        }  

        return this;  
    }  

    public void paint(Graphics g) {  
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;  
        g2.setClip(0,0,500,500);  
        g2.setColor(new Color(60,179,113));  
        g2.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.BOLD,12));  
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();  
        at.setToTranslation(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());  
        g2.transform(at);  
        double radianAngle = ( ((double)m_degreesRotation) / ((double)180) ) * Math.PI;  
        at.setToRotation(radianAngle);  
        g2.transform(at);  
        g2.drawString(this.getText(), 0.0f, 0.0f);  
    }  
}
```

This is not my own, taken from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/346914/GUI/java/JTableHeader)

Comment: well that's for cells not headers.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would helps!!

```
public VerticalTableHeaderCellRenderer() {
        setHorizontalAlignment(LEFT);
        setHorizontalTextPosition(CENTER);
        setVerticalAlignment(CENTER);
        setVerticalTextPosition(TOP);
        setUI(new VerticalLabelUI());        
    }

TableCellRenderer headerRenderer = new VerticalTableHeaderCellRenderer();
int colCount = j.getColumnCount();  //J is JTable object
for(int i =1; i<colCount; i++){
             j.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setHeaderRenderer(headerRenderer);
        }
```